# datatable searching according to words matches in jquery

Tags: jquery, search, datatables

I am using this code:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function (event) {
    tableClause.search(txt.trim(), true, true).draw();
});
```

Example: if any user searches "Limitation of funds" or "Limitation funds" or "Limitation for funds" or "the Limitation of funds" I want to show matching words result in an entire row.

Comment: Basically what your saying is irrespective of the input entered being uppercase or lower case you want the results to be compared and displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

**This Should do the trick** ;

```
$("#filter").keyup(function(){

    tableClause.search($(this).val()).draw();

});
```